# best way to center div with image on right?

Tags: css

I want the price and currency to be centered ? what is the best way to do it ?

```css
.currency {
  background: url(../css/images/currency.png);
  background-size: 30px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position-x: center;
  background-position-y: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="price1" class="pricebox">
  <div class="titleabo"><strong>3</strong>jours</div>
  <div class="price">
    <div class="howmuch">300<div class="currency"></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: show us full code, as you can see .. we see nothing

Comment: I want to center  a price with the currency on his right ! i want the currency + price to be CENTERED but not just the price centered with currency on right

Comment: @amphetamachine no need to convert to a snippet a non working code ... you won't help him, you simply make his question more irrelevant

Comment: do you see any currency in the code you provided ?

Comment: @VXp maybe diagonally, who knows ...

Comment: the funny thing is that you have 10 related links in the right of your question all related to centering ... well i will let someone else close this, i closed a lot today

Answer (score 0):

**The `div` must have a `text-align` defined**

See the following:

*Added border to better viewing*

```css
.currency {
background: url(../css/images/currency.png);
background-size: 30px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position-x: center;
background-position-y: center;
}

.pricebox{
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}

.price{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="price1" class="pricebox">
<div class="titleabo"><strong>3</strong>jours</div>
<div class="price"><div class="howmuch">300<div class="currency"></div> </div></div>
```

Comment: but i want the currency to be centered with text ? how can i do that

Comment: `The div must have a width defined` --> why ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif Because if it is not defined, the `text-align: center` will have no effect (there is nothing to center if there is no width)

Comment: euh ... we are talking about a div right? a div is a block element that has 100% width by default

Comment: @Slown1970 You should add the `height` and the `width` for the currency. If the .price and .currency doesn't show at the same line, add `float: left;` to them. *Keep in mind the `float: left` kind of "remove" the element size. You will need a `clear: both;` element right after it*

Comment: @TemaniAfif Oh, right! My mistake, sorry. Already corrected it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way , i just added an img instead of a div with a background , and used " text-align : center " didnt know it was actually working with image